# Configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check on Apple M1

Tags: c++, makefile, apple-m1, configure

I have already reviewed pretty much all solutions on similar issues, but still haven't figured out my problem. Here's the situation: there is a `./configure` script I'm trying to run so that I can have make files to run the `make` command. Everytime I run the script I get the following error:

```
configure: error: in `/Users/my-username/tools/ViennaRNA-2.6.3/build':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

Based on some suggested solutions for sanity check failure, I checked and saw there's no `/lib/cpp` path, so after running `which cpp` I see my `cpp` path is:

```
/usr/local/bin/cpp
```

So in the `./configure` script, I replaced all the `/lib/cpp` paths with this new path. But I still get the same error (with the path updated to `/usr/local/bin/cpp`). I tried updating the `CPP` environment variable too, but no luck.

I'm running this script on **Apple M1 Pro** and **macOS Ventura Version 13.5.2**.

**Edits**:
The log is pretty long, but some errors I see in the `config.log`:

```
configure:3991: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files

clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:4002: $? = 1
configure:3991: gcc -version >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-version'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
```

And,

```
conftest.c:47:10: fatal error: 'minix/config.h' file not found
```

And,

```
configure:5931: g++ -V >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

And,

```
/usr/local/include/c++/7.4.0/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/7.4.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
```

And end of `config.log` including the last error I get before the sanity check failure:

```
configure:6381: /usr/local/bin/cpp  conftest.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/7.4.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/7.4.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from conftest.cpp:38:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/7.4.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:6381: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "ViennaRNA"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ViennaRNA"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.6.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "ViennaRNA 2.6.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "rna@tbi.univie.ac.at"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA"
| #define HAVE_STDIO_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_WCHAR_H 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define _ALL_SOURCE 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _HPUX_ALT_XOPEN_SOCKET_API 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define _OPENBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_ATTRIBS_EXT__ 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__ 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_DFP_EXT__ 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_FUNCS_EXT__ 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__ 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1
| #define __STDC_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
| #define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
| #define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
| #define PACKAGE "ViennaRNA"
| #define VERSION "2.6.3"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <limits.h>
|            Syntax error
configure:6414: error: in `/Users/phosseini/tools/ViennaRNA-2.6.3/build':
configure:6416: error: C++ preprocessor "/usr/local/bin/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
    

/* confdefs.h */
    #define PACKAGE_NAME "ViennaRNA"
    #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ViennaRNA"
    #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.6.3"
    #define PACKAGE_STRING "ViennaRNA 2.6.3"
    #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "rna@tbi.univie.ac.at"
    #define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA"
    #define HAVE_STDIO_H 1
    #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
    #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
    #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
    #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
    #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
    #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
    #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
    #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
    #define HAVE_WCHAR_H 1
    #define STDC_HEADERS 1
    #define _ALL_SOURCE 1
    #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
    #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
    #define _HPUX_ALT_XOPEN_SOCKET_API 1
    #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
    #define _OPENBSD_SOURCE 1
    #define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_ATTRIBS_EXT__ 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_BFP_EXT__ 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_DFP_EXT__ 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_FUNCS_EXT__ 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__ 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1
    #define __STDC_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
    #define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
    #define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
    #define PACKAGE "ViennaRNA"
    #define VERSION "2.6.3"
    
    configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Have you checked the "`config.log' for more details"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just added some log info as an edit.

Comment: By default, gcc and g++ on a Mac are just symlinks to clang and clang++ (they are largely, but not entirely, compatible option-wise). You might need a "real" g++. (The log is expected to contain errors, as the configuration procedure tries numerous options in order to figure out what your system looks like.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I've already installed g++ using homebrew and have g++-13 and gcc-13 installed at `/opt/homebrew/bin`. Should I check the soft/symbolic links?

Comment: What does the end of `config.log` look like?

Comment: In that case there's probably a conflict somewhere in your setup. For instance, it looks like you have `/usr/local/bin` before `/opt/homebrew/bin` in `$PATH`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles just added the end of the log as an edit

Comment: We need the last errors in the log, those are the ones that likely caused configure to fail

Comment: @AlanBirtles just added the last error too before the end of the log.

Comment: There are a few other questions with the same problem https://www.google.com/search?q=limits.h:+No+such+file+or+directory+macos+site:stackoverflow.com